# How to request extra header when requesting a web page through HTTP in JAVA?

Tags: java, android, http

So I'm trying to create an android app and request some information from the following website:
https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2
However, to gain access you need to pass token (I already have) but it has to be seperate then the URL.
So the format is:

```
"token:<token>" "url"
```

And one example is:

```
curl -H "token:fjgYwUtcBDuksNyeiUjqFMGZZWZTogXb" "https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/locations?datasetid=GSOM"
```

if you request using just the url you get denied. I'm using the curl command in linux and it works fine. How do I do the same thing only in JAVA?

Comment: The answer varies by HTTP client API (`HttpUrlConnection`, OkHttp, etc.). Which one are you planning on using?

Comment: I have no idea about any of this, sorry. I'm just looking for what works. The website I'm using does not provide any of these details, simply states that they are using the curl command.

Comment: "I have no idea about any of this, sorry" -- then you need to start by choosing an HTTP client API. Any decent HTTP client API allows you to set custom headers. However, we cannot decide for you how you want to make HTTP requests in an Android app (since you have tagged this question with `android`). So, learn enough about Android and your HTTP API options to decide which one you would like to use. If, while doing that, you did not run across how to add a custom HTTP header, ask on Stack Overflow how to do that for the specific HTTP API that you chose.